# Integrate JavaScript support in a PDF viewer/reader using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, adobe

I have a Windows form based PDF reader application, the application can read all PDF files. But the application cannot handle JavaScript action and function on which file does have Acroform with JavaScript function/action.

So, now I need to make JavaScript support for PDF files on my PDF viewer application, that's how JavaScript from PDF file would be executable in viewing mode like Adobe/PDF Exchange/Nuance. What would be the best solution for winform PDF viewer application for making this support.

Comment: "Windows form based PDF reader application" What is actually rendering the PDF on screen? A 3rd party library? Browser? OS?

Comment: Good luck. Commercial applications like Foxit, Kofax (Nuance), and Nitro haven't been able to completely reproduce the JavaScript interpreter in Acrobat. I suggest you rethink your solution.